# bulk rename using powershell to get rid of 9 characters that follow a "-"

Tags: powershell, batch-rename

I need to rename around 5000 files that have the following naming format:

"322xxx-710yy.tiff"

i need to remove -710yy from the name to get 322xxxx.tiff

can anyone suggest a rename-item command for power-shell to do this?

i tried:

```
    get-childitem -filter "322*" -recurse | Rename-item -NewName{$_.name -replace '-710*', ''}
```

but all that does is remove the "710" leaving the remaining characters after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-replace` takes a regex, not a wildcard match (unlike the `-Filter` parameter of `Get-ChildItem`), so you need

```
$_.Name -replace '-710[^.]*'
```

instead (you can also leave out the `, ''` in that case, as it's implied). Note that I'm only replacing non-dot characters after the 710, to keep the extension intact.

Comment: Joey, you just saved my noodle buddy! thank you so much.